# Qual a importância de implementar o método hashCode em Java?

Tags: java

1. Qual a importância de implementar o método hashCode em Java?
2. De que forma o método hashCode diferencia dois objetos?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

O `hashCode()` é usado para objetos do tipo [Collection](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html) organizar seus elementos, como por exemplo, em uma academia que possui as fichas de alunos separados pela primeira letra do do nome aluno, aquelas abinhas `A`, `B`, `C`, ... dentro de uma pasta ou porta-documentos (ok, hoje é tudo via sistemas, mas todo mundo lembra das fichas de papel, não lembra?).

Isso facilita encontrar o nome de um aluno no meio de tantos. Se você quer encontrar o aluno John você primeiro pega todo mundo que começa coma letra J e daí você busca dentro das possibilidades o nome exato que você precisa, o número de matrícula, etc, ao invés de procurar entre todos os alunos matriculados na academia.

Procurar pela aba com a primeira letra do nome da aluno seria equivalente à busca pelo `hashCode()`, procurar pelo nome exato do aluno seria equivalente à busca pela `equals()`.

Vamos a um exemplo, imagine a classe Produto abaixo já com o `hashCode()` e o `equals()` implementados:

```
public class Produto {
    int idProduto;
    String nomeProduto;

    public Produto(int idProduto, String nomeProduto) {
        super();
        this.idProduto = idProduto;
        this.nomeProduto = nomeProduto;
    }

    //getters and setters aqui!

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        //deve ser o mesmo resultado para um mesmo objeto, não pode ser aleatório
        return this.idProduto;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        //se nao forem objetos da mesma classe sao objetos diferentes
        if(!(obj instanceof Produto)) return false; 

        //se forem o mesmo objeto, retorna true
        if(obj == this) return true;

        // aqui o cast é seguro por causa do teste feito acima
        Produto produto = (Produto) obj; 

        //aqui você compara a seu gosto, o ideal é comparar atributo por atributo
        return this.idProduto == produto.getIdProduto() &&
                this.nomeProduto.equals(produto.getNomeProduto());
    }   
}
```

Agora suponha que desejamos criar um objeto do tipo Collection, digamos, um `HashSet<>()`, e armazenar uma lista de vários objetos do tipo Produto:

```
public class TesteCollection {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Set<Produto> produtos = new HashSet<>();

        produtos.add(new Produto(1, "Caderno 96 folhas"));
        produtos.add(new Produto(2, "Lapis 2B"));
        produtos.add(new Produto(3, "Borracha"));
        produtos.add(new Produto(4, "Estojo"));

        //em algum ponto do programa que você não possui mais
        //a variável de referência para o objeto que você quer
        //encontrar na lista
        Produto p = new Produto(4, "Estojo");
        System.out.println(produtos.contains(p));
    }
}
```

No método `contains()`, o set precisa **procurar** o produto em sua coleção de produtos, o método retorna `true` ou `false` informando se encontrou ou não. Você chama o método passando uma variável de referência do tipo Produto e pergunta se esse produto está contido no set, entretanto, como você teve que criar um novo objeto (observe a palavra `new` na linha de cima) esse novo objeto NÃO ESTÁ no set, o que você tem nesse ponto é um objeto novo, e pode ser que haja um objeto dentro do set que possui os mesmos atributos identificadores (os atributos que você considerou relevantes  e colocou dentro do seu `equals()`), geralmente isso é o que precisamos, um novo objeto com os atributos identificadores idênticos e não o real objeto dentro da coleção.

No `contains()` a lista primeiro pega todos os objetos dentro de sua coleção que possuem o mesmo `hashCode()`, depois ela procura dentre todos os objetos encontrados qual é igual de acordo com a implementação do `equals()`, no exemplo acima, o retorno é `true`.

**EDIT**

> O hashCode agrupa objetos conforme uma condição prévia, a exemplo da ficha de alunos que agrupa alunos por letra?

Sim, as coleções agrupam os objetos que possuem exatamente o mesmo `hashCode()`.

> É usado para comparar objetos dentro de coleções?

Não é usado para comparar, mas é usado para encontrar objetos dentro da coleção, pois primeiro procura-se o grupo ao qual o objeto pertence em seguida procura-se o objeto fazendo a comparação de objetos, logo, se não for possível encontrar o grupo não será possível encontrar o objeto. A comparação de objetos é feita através do resultado do método `equals()`.

A implementação **correta** do `hashCode()` é aquela que sempre retorna o mesmo valor quando chamado para um mesmo objeto, de acordo com o [contrato do hashCode()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29).

Além de implementar corretamente deve-se sempre procurar implementar o `hashCode()` eficientemente. Quando implementado de uma maneira eficiente ele ajuda as coleções a eliminarem vários objetos que com certeza não são o que está sendo procurado, ou seja, ele descarta os grupos de objetos que não produzem determinado `hashCode()`.

Um exemplo de implementação de `hashCode()` ineficiente:

```
public int hashCode() { return 42; } //é válido, porém ineficiente
```

É ineficiente pois todos os objetos estarão em um mesmo grupo, dificultando o trabalho da coleção ao se procurar um objeto. A forma mais eficiente de implementação é se você conseguir garantir uma forma de gerar `hashCode()`s únicos para cada objeto, assim você estará garantindo que haverá apenas um objeto por grupo de `hashCode()` dentro da coleção.

Comment: *Math*, muito boa a sua explicação. Contudo, não ficou claro para mim a forma como o hashCode funciona. O equals, como seu exemplo bem explicou, compara dois objetos pelo valor contido nos seus atributos. E o hashCode como funciona? Você pode adicionar um exemplo disso na sua resposta?

Comment: Você não entendeu qual parte? Como deve ser a implementação do equals ou como a lista o usa em suas buscas?

Comment: Seria correto eu afirmar: 1) o hashCode agrupa objetos conforme uma condição prévia, a exemplo da ficha de alunos que agrupa alunos por letra. 2) é usado para comparar objetos dentro de coleções.

Comment: *Math*, uma das minhas principais dúvidas é como as coleções usam o método hashCode para realizar suas buscas.

Comment: Embora eu concorde que o `hashCode` não é, estritamente falando, usado para comparar objetos dentro de coleções, isso dá a impressão que o `hashCode` não é usado ao se procurar objetos dentro de coleções, o que não é o caso. Um dos grandes bugs no uso de `hashCode` é o uso de campos mutáveis, o que pode levar um objeto a ser "perdido" dentro de uma coleção, já que o `hashCode` é usado como uma espécie de pré-filtro.

Comment: @DanielC.Sobral concordo plenamente, se o `grupo` não for encontrado não há como encontrar o objeto. Você acha que minha resposta deixou isso obscuro?

Comment: Não diria que está obscuro: é uma conclusão natural daquilo que você falou, mas minha impressão é que muita gente não faz essa conclusão. Eu preferiria que este tipo de situação fosse explicitamente abordado.