# Remover objetos duplicados de List<MinhaClasse>

Tags: java, collection

Galera é o seguinte, eu tenho uma classe modelo com atributos que armazenam dados retornados do banco de dados. Por exemplo:

```
public class RelacaoTransformacao {
    /** ID do registro no banco de dados. */
    private long id;
    /** Indica se o teste já foi concluído. */
    private boolean concluido;
    /** O valor do teste. */
    private double valor;
    // ...O restante do código.
}
```

Tendo o código abaixo como exemplo:

```
// Percorre o cursor obtendo todos os dados e criando um objeto com os dados retornados.
            while ( result.moveToNext() ) {
                long id = result.getLong( result.getColumnIndex( br.com.bhdnet.softencal.app.database.enums.RelacaoTransformacao.COLUNA_ID.texto ) );
                boolean concluido = result.getInt( result.getColumnIndex( br.com.bhdnet.softencal.app.database.enums.RelacaoTransformacao.COLUNA_CONCLUIDO.texto ) ) > 0 ;
                double valor = result.getDouble( result.getColumnIndex( br.com.bhdnet.softencal.app.database.enums.RelacaoTransformacao.COLUNA_VALOR.texto ) );
                int polaridade = result.getInt( result.getColumnIndex( br.com.bhdnet.softencal.app.database.enums.RelacaoTransformacao.COLUNA_POLARIDADE.texto ) );
                String observacao = result.getString( result.getColumnIndex( br.com.bhdnet.softencal.app.database.enums.RelacaoTransformacao.COLUNA_OBSERVACAO.texto ) );
                long idPrimario = result.getLong( result.getColumnIndex( br.com.bhdnet.softencal.app.database.enums.RelacaoTransformacao.COLUNA_FK_ENROLAMENTO_TCTP_ID1.texto ) );
                long idSecundario = result.getLong( result.getColumnIndex( br.com.bhdnet.softencal.app.database.enums.RelacaoTransformacao.COLUNA_FK_ENROLAMENTO_TCTP_ID2.texto ) );
                String primario = result.getString( result.getColumnIndex( br.com.bhdnet.softencal.app.database.enums.EnrolamentoTcTp.COLUNA_ENROLAMENTO.texto ) );
                primario += String.valueOf( result.getInt( result.getColumnIndex( br.com.bhdnet.softencal.app.database.enums.EnrolamentoTcTp.COLUNA_NUMERO_ENROLAMENTO.texto ) ) );

                RelacaoTransformacao relacaoTransformacao = new RelacaoTransformacao( id, concluido, valor, polaridade, observacao, idPrimario, idSecundario, primario, null );
                // Adiciona o objeto enrolamento a lista de enrolamentos
                listRelacaoTransformacao.add( relacaoTransformacao );
            }
```

Eu sempre vou ter dois objetos repetidos na minha lista pelo atributo ID, isso devido a minha busca no banco de dados (Não preciso explicar essa busca, apenas entenda que eu realmente preciso retornar dois registros repetidos, porque em uma coluna do registro repetido o valor vai ser diferente e eu preciso pegar este valor). Como eu faço para obter um desses objetos repetidos pelo ID e então removê-lo da lista?

Comment: Qual critério você usa para saber qual dos objetos você vai remover?

Comment: Refraseando a pergunta do @Math (que pode ser interpretada como perguntando sobre o critério de duplicação, que é dois objetos terem o mesmo ID): supondo que haja dois objetos com o mesmo ID, qual dos dois deve ser removido? Qualquer um?

Comment: Não pode ser qualquer um. O que deve ser removido deve ser o segundo objeto. Só que antes de remover eu vou pegar um certo atributo dele, e setar no primeiro objeto, então depois disso posso removê-lo.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Você pode fazer um for dentro do outro, percorrendo a lista e armazenando em variáveis diferentes cada objeto da lista, daí você compara os id, se o id for o mesmo e não for o mesmo objeto você entra na sua lógica de escolher qual dos dois deve ser removido.

Adicione esses elementos que devem ser removidos em uma lista a parte para removê-los após a verificação dentro dos fors.

Exemplo:

```
public class LucasSantos {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<RelacaoTransformacao> listRelacaoTransformacao = new ArrayList<>(); 
        List<RelacaoTransformacao> listEliminar = new ArrayList<>(); 
        listRelacaoTransformacao.add(new RelacaoTransformacao(1, true, 2));
        listRelacaoTransformacao.add(new RelacaoTransformacao(1, true, 5));
        listRelacaoTransformacao.add(new RelacaoTransformacao(2, true, 5));
        listRelacaoTransformacao.add(new RelacaoTransformacao(2, true, 1));
        System.out.println("Antes");
        for(RelacaoTransformacao r: listRelacaoTransformacao) {
            System.out.println(r);
        }

        // Faz um for percorrendo os itens da lista. Para cada item da lista percorrido, faz um outro for para percorrer todos os itens da lista novamente (Pulando o primeiro item do for externo)
        // para verificar qual objeto tem id igual ao objeto do for mais externo e se são objetos diferentes.
        for ( int i = 0; i < listRelacaoTransformacao.size(); i++ ) {
            for ( int j = i + 1; j < listRelacaoTransformacao.size(); j++ ) {
                // Se os objetos tiverem o mesmo id mas forem objetos diferentes, entao pegamos o campo primario do segundo objeto e o colocamos no campo secundario da primeiro objeto.
                // Adicionamos o segundo objeto na lista para eliminação de objetos repetidos.
                if ( listRelacaoTransformacao.get( i ).getId() == listRelacaoTransformacao.get( j ).getId() &&
                    !( ( (Object) listRelacaoTransformacao.get( i ) ).equals( listRelacaoTransformacao.get( j ) ) )  ) {

                    // Aqui você faz o que quiser.
                    i++; // Incrementa i em 1 para evitar verificações desnecessárias.
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
        //elimina todos os elementos que foram marcados para remoção
        listRelacaoTransformacao.removeAll(listEliminar);
        System.out.println("Depois");
        for(RelacaoTransformacao r: listRelacaoTransformacao) {
            System.out.println(r);
        }
    }
}
```

Saída:

> Antes
>   RelacaoTransformacao [id=1, concluido=true, valor=2.0]
>   RelacaoTransformacao [id=1, concluido=true, valor=5.0]
>   RelacaoTransformacao [id=2, concluido=true, valor=5.0]
>   RelacaoTransformacao [id=2, concluido=true, valor=1.0]
>   RelacaoTransformacao [id=3, concluido=true, valor=2.0]
>   Depois
>   RelacaoTransformacao [id=1, concluido=true, valor=2.0]
>   RelacaoTransformacao [id=2, concluido=true, valor=1.0]

**Observação**: sempre que fizer comparações de objetos sobrescreva o método equals(), e se você estiver trabalhando com Set sobrescreva também o hashCode(). A interface List não usa o método hashCode() entretanto a própria documentação recomenda você sempre sobrescreve-lo quando sobrescrever o equals. A documentação da classe Object diz:

> equals(): Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.

Em tradução livre:

> equals(): Note que é geralmente necessário sobrescrever o método hashCode sempre que esse método for sobrescrito, pois assim mantém o contrato do método hashCode, que diz que objetos iguais devem ter hash codes iguais.

Mais informações do que é o método hashCode() :

[Qual a importância de implementar o método hashCode em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11108/3117)

Documentação: [equals(), Class Object - Java SE 7](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29)

Comment: Por favor evitem longas discussões nos comentários; a conversa de vocês foi [movida para o chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/54264/discussion-on-answer-by-math-remover-objetos-duplicados-de-listminhaclasse)

Answer (score 7):

Use uma classe que implemente um conjunto (`Set`), como [TreeSet](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/TreeSet.html#add%28E%29). Forneça um `Comparator` no construtor que use o ID.

As classes que implementam `Set` somente permitem elementos distintos, usando como parâmetro os campos usados no `Comparator`.

Comment: Se a ordem dos elementos na lista não importar, essa é a solução mais simples. Inserir elementos em um `Set` (conjunto), no qual elementos não se repetem.

Comment: @utluiz, com base no meu comentário na minha pergunta que digo que o objeto a ser removido sempre será o segundo e eu preciso pegar um atributo do mesmo antes de removê-lo, qual a melhor implementação para o meu problema? A sua ou a do usuário Math. Do seu ponto de vista.

Comment: @LucasSantos Se você quer obter dados dos elementos repetidos, então terá que implementar uma solução como a do @Math. Entretanto, o algoritmo dele está com complexidade O(n²), isto é, ele compara todos com todos. Isso poderia ser otimizado para O(log(n)) usando duas variáveis `i` e `j` nos for's e sempre iniciando `j` com `i + 1`.

Comment: @Piovezan, um conjunto set não deixa os elementos ordenados? Nem mesmo se eu inseri-los dentro do conjunto na ordem?

Comment: @LucasSantos Se for um [LinkedHashSet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashSet.html), pode-se iterar pelos elementos na ordem em que foram inseridos.

Comment: Valeu Piovezan. @utluiz obrigado pela dica e resposta, eu entendi o que você falou mas pergunto. Isso fará muita diferença no desempenho? Digo isso porque a lista provavelmente terá apenas 6 elementos em ocasiões raras. Se são 6 elementos então temos 6x2 porque tem as repetições. Aconselha mesmo assim eu usar `i` e `j` ao invés do `for each`?

Comment: @LucasSantos Para 6 elementos não vale a pena otimizar o algoritmo.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta @utluiz e @ Piovezan. Como a resposta que vou utilizar será a do @ Math , entao, vou marcá-la como aceita. Mas se pudesse marcava as duas pois ambas me acrescentaram conhecimento.

Comment: @LucasSantos Sem problemas, o importante é você ter entendido.

Comment: @utluiz realmente tive que fazer como você disse por aqui em comentário, referente a otimização...Você disse: `Isso poderia ser otimizado para O(log(n)) usando duas variáveis i e j nos for's e sempre iniciando j com i + 1`. Realmente tive que fazer assim e acrescentar um pouco mais para melhorar a otimização mais ainda. E também não foi só questão de otimização, do jeito do @Math ficou com um erro de lógica que não deu certo no meu caso. A resposta dele foi editada com o código correto.