# Mapear composite IDS

Tags: hibernate

Estou com um problema ao mapear uma classe no Hibernate 2.

Tenho uma tabela "CONF_PGTO_CLIENTE" que possui colunas (ID_LOJA, ID_CLIENTE, TIPO_PGTO), todas as 3 colunas são primary keys e preciso mapear isso no ".hbm.xml".

A minha classe é:

```
/**
 * Configuração de quais clientes podem utilizar determinada forma de pagamento.
 *
 * @hibernate.class
 *      table="CONF_CLIENTE_PGTO"
 */
public class ClienteFormaPgto {

    private Long idLoja;
    private int tipoPgto;

    private Set clientesPermitidos;

    /**
     * @hibernate.key-property 
     *  column="ID_LOJA"
     *  not-null="true"
     *  type="java.lang.Long"
     */
    public Long getIdLoja() {
        return idLoja;
    }

    public void setIdLoja(Long idLoja) {
        this.idLoja = idLoja;
    }

    /**
     * @hibernate.key-property 
     *  column="TIPO_PGTO"
     *  not-null="true"
     *  type="int"
     */
    public int getTipoPgto() {
        return tipoPgto;
    }

    public void setTipoPgto(int tipoPgto) {
        this.tipoPgto = tipoPgto;
    }

    /**
     * 
     * @hibernate.set
     *  table="CLIENTE"
     *  lazy="false"
     *  cascade="none"
     * @hibernate.collection-key
     *  column="ID_CLIENTE"
     * @hibernate.collection-many-to-many
     *  column="ID"
     *  class="net.alforria.b2c.modelo.Cliente"
     */
    public Set getClientesPermitidos() {
        return clientesPermitidos;
    }

    public void setClientesPermitidos(Set clientesPermitidos) {
        this.clientesPermitidos = clientesPermitidos;
    }

}
```

e meu .hbm.xml está assim:

```
<hibernate-mapping
>
    <class
        name="net.alforria.b2c.modelo.ClienteFormaPgto"
        table="CONF_CLIENTE_PGTO"
    >

        <composite-id>
            <key-property name="idLoja" column="ID_LOJA" type="java.lang.Long" />
            <key-property name="tipoPgto" column="TIPO_PGTO" type="int" />
        </composite-id>

        <set
            name="clientesPermitidos"
            table="CLIENTE"
            lazy="false"
            cascade="none"
            sort="unsorted"
        >

            <key
                column="ID_CLIENTE"
            >
            </key>

            <many-to-many
                class="net.alforria.b2c.modelo.Cliente"
                column="ID"
                outer-join="auto"
             />

        </set>

    </class>

</hibernate-mapping>
```

Já tentei diversas variações deste mapeamento, mas nada que eu faça parece funcionar...

---

@Jônatas Hudler

Então, o que acontece é que ao executar um find q tenho do meu DAO, o resultado vem vazio sempre...

a hql q executo é:

```
public List findClientesByFormaPgto(Long idLoja, int tipoPgto) {
    List list = findByQuery(
            " select ccp.idLoja, ccp.idCliente, c.nome " +
            " from " + ClienteFormaPgto.class.getName() + " as ccp " +
            " , " + Cliente.class.getName() + " as c" +
            " where ccp.idLoja = ? " +
            " and ccp.tipoPgto = ? " +
            " and ccp.idCliente = c.id",
            new Object[] {idLoja, tipoPgto},
            new Type[] {Hibernate.LONG, Hibernate.INTEGER}
    );
    return list;

}
```

a função findByQuery() vem implementada de uma outra classe BaseDAO. E recebe como parâmetros uma query hql, uma lista de parâmetros, e uma lista que informa a tipagem dos itens dos paramêtros dados no parametro 2.

Não vem mensagens de erro nem nada do tipo.

@Topic

Como solução temporaria, acrescentei no banco e no mapeamento, um id, assim contornei o problema do "composite-id"... Porém não é a solução ideal para meu caso, que seria com as 3 colunas do banco como primary keys...

Comment: As anotações estão dentro dos blocos de comentários, isso esta correto?

Comment: Sim, este é o formato que trabalha o Hibernate 2...

Comment: Quando você cita "mas nada que eu faça parece funcionar": o que de fato ocorre? Mensagem de erro? Query's SQL geradas de forma incorreta? Poderias fazer a gentileza de prover mais informações neste sentido?

Answer (score 0):

Mude os 2 mapeamentos para o mesmo tipo.
E implemente os metodos equal e hashcode.

Comment: Podes desenvolver a resposta mais?

Comment: Realmente, ficou meio vaga sua resposta... 

Quanto a colocar os mapeamentos do mesmo tipo, creio não poder fazer isso de forma eficaz, isso me faria criar validações desnecessárias.

Quanto a implementar estes métodos, o que você quer dizer? O problema poderia estar nos métodos e não no mapeamento?

Comment: Declara ambos como Long.

Comment: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11108/qual-a-import%C3%A2ncia-de-implementar-o-m%C3%A9todo-hashcode-em-java

Comment: Na documentação do Hibernate 2 ele indica que voce deve implementar esses métodos (equals e hashcode) caso utilize chaves compostas.