# Como sobrescrever método equals?

Tags: java, método

Estou tentando sobrescrever o método equals para em vez de validar se um objeto inteiro é igual ao outro apenas verificar se um valor
neste objeto é igual ao outro.

**Cenário Real:**
Objeto Aluno sendo ele. nome e rg, e idade se o rg for igual quer dizer que eles são a mesma pessoa.

**Classe Aluno:**

```
public class Aluno {

   private static String nome;
   private static float rg;
   private static int idade;

   public Aluno(String nome, float rg, int idade) {
      this.nome = nome;
      this.rg = rg;
      this.idade = idade;
   }

   public boolean equals(Aluno a) {
      boolean result = false;
      if (this.getRg() == a.getRg()) {
         result = true;
      }
      return result;
   }   

   // getters and setters

}
```

**Classe Main:**

```
public class main {

   public static void main(String[] args) {
      Aluno a1 = new Aluno("A", 12, 20);
      Aluno a2 = new Aluno("B", 11, 25);
      Aluno a3 = new Aluno("A", 25, 28);
      Aluno a4 = new Aluno("D", 12, 21);
      System.out.println(a1.equals(a3)); // aqui deveria retornar false
      System.out.println(a1.equals(a4)); // aqui deveria retornar true
   }
}
```

Pelo visto estou fazendo uma confusão em pegar o "this"  que é o valor do objeto antes do .equals.

Comment: Você quer sobrescrever o `equals()` que herda do `Object`, certo?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tem dois problemas no seu código:

1. Você definiu variáveis estáticas para sua classe Aluno, quer dizer que todos os objetos dessa classe compartilharão dos mesmos valores para as variáveis. Remova o `static` delas que já é para seu código funcionar corretamente;
2. Seu método `equals()` não está sobrescrevendo corretamente o método `equals()` da classe Object, embora também funcionaria pois você está fazendo uma chamada explícita ao método `equals()` da classe Aluno, mas pode ficar confuso.

O código abaixo roda corretamente:

```
class Aluno {
   private String nome;
   private float rg;
   private int idade;

   public Aluno(String nome, float rg, int idade) {
      this.nome = nome;
      this.rg = rg;
      this.idade = idade;
   }

   @Override
   public boolean equals(Object o) {
      boolean result = false;
      if (this.getRg() == ((Aluno)o).getRg()) {
         result = true;
      }
      return result;
   }   

   public float getRg() {
     return this.rg;
   }
}

class Ideone
{
    public static void main (String[] args)
    {
      Aluno a1 = new Aluno("A", 12, 20);
      Aluno a2 = new Aluno("B", 11, 25);
      Aluno a3 = new Aluno("A", 25, 28);
      Aluno a4 = new Aluno("D", 12, 21);
      System.out.println(a1.equals(a3)); // aqui retorna false
      System.out.println(a1.equals(a4)); // aqui retorna true
    }
}
```

Veja no [Ideone](https://ideone.com/NfJGI3).

Como regra geral, de acordo com a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object)) do Java, sempre que sobrescrever o método `equals()` deve-se sobrescrever também o `hashCode()`. Texto original em inglês:

> Note that it is generally necessary to override the hashCode method whenever this method is overridden, so as to maintain the general contract for the hashCode method, which states that equal objects must have equal hash codes.

Para o caso em questão pode-se deixar isso de lado pois o `equals()` já não segue o contrato estabelecido na documentação já que ele deveria por exemplo verificar se a variável contém referência nula ou se referencia um objeto de outro tipo. Eu não pus isso no código pois acho que foge um pouco do escopo da pergunta, uma resposta mais detalhada sobre o assunto pode ser encontrada aqui: [Qual a importância de implementar o método hashCode em Java?](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11114/3117)

Para o caso em questão, entretanto, pode manter assim sabendo das dívida técnica que seu código possui, ou pode ainda mudar o nome do método `equals()` para algum outro, caso queira deixar mais claro ainda que ele não é **o** método `equals()` da classe Object.

Comment: esse static na minha vida ta pior que `;`, massa é esse Casting loco de Object

Comment: fazer apenas `   public boolean equals(Aluno a) {
      boolean result = false;
      if (this.getRg() == a.getRg()) {
         result = true;
      }
      return result;
   }` funciona, tem problema ?

Comment: Não tem problema não, mas talvez fosse uma boa ideia mudar o nome do método `equals()` para algum outro para você não confundir com o `equals()` da classe Object. Mas como me parece ser um código pequeno diria que não chega a ser essencial. Se fizer assim vai funcionar também.

Comment: Dei uma atualizada na resposta, se quiser dar uma olhada.