# Como remover Objetos duplicados em um ArrayList?

Tags: java, classificação

Olá eu tenho um arrayList de objetos. porem esses objetos acabam se repetindo, então eu queria uma naneira de remover os duplicados.

eu já tentei usar o  hasSet, porem parece que ele não funciona com objetos.

```
Set nova = new HashSet<>();
nova.addAll(Objetos);
Objetos.clear();
Objetos.addAll(nova);
```

já tentei usar uma comparação if porem não deu certo também.

```
List<T> naoDuplicado = new ArrayList<T>();
for (T obj : naoDuplicado) {
    if (!naoDuplicado.contains(Obj)) {
        naoDuplicado.add(element);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você pode e deve sim usar o [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html), mas o objeto que você está adicionando na coleção deve implementar o método [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add-E-) (e [hashCode](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode--)). Pois é através do [equals](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) que o [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) define a duplicidade.

Implementar nesse contexto, significa você reimplementar/sobrescrever o método de acordo com sua regra de igualdade.

A resposta da [pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122978/como-sobrescrever-m%C3%A9todo-equals) deve ajudar na sua implementação.