# Collection para uso em estoque

Tags: java, collection, coleção

Qual a melhor implementação da interface Collection para implementação de uma classe de estoque?
Por exemplo, um estoque de produtos de supermercado.

O meu cenário é o seguinte:
Um sistema de gerência de estoque de um supermercados, essa coleção faria o pepel de banco de dados dos produtos, guardando a quantidade de itens que o estoque ainda possui de determinado produto. Não se pode ter itens duplicados. Quanto a ordenação, não sei se é necessária ou não.

Comment: Precisamos que nos exemplifique um cenário para melhor lhe propor as possibilidades de trabalhar com Collections. Por exemplo, se utilizar Collections ordenadas, não ordenadas, as que não suportam itens duplicados etc.

Comment: Editei colocando mais informações.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você precisa criar um relacionamento entre uma chave e um valor. No caso, precisa mapear produtos para suas respectivas quantidades.

Quem faz isso no Java é a interface `Map`. Sua implementação mais simples é a classe `HashMap`. Nesse tipo de collections, chaves são únicas e não podem ser repetidas.

O tipo de dado representando a quantidade é simples: pode ser um `Integer`. Já o produto vai depender de como você quer representá-lo. Seria com um id numérico de produto (ou seja, um outro `Integer`)? Ou talvez uma tag, que poderia ser uma `String`?

Ficaria assim então:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> produtosParaQuantidades = new HashMap<>();
```

ou então:

```
Map<String, Integer> produtosParaQuantidades = new HashMap<>();
```

Aí você pode adicionar e recuperar quantidades assim:

```
int idDoSabãoEmPó = 5;
produtosParaQuantidades.put(idDoSabãoEmPó, 100);
int quantidadeDeSabãoEmPó = produtosParaQuantidades.get(idDoSabãoEmPó);
```

Comment: Pensei em utilizar uma classe Produto, que encapsularia os dados de um produto, como nome e valor.

Comment: Pode ser também. Neste caso, para que dois produtos iguais (mesmo nome e valor) possam ser tratados como uma única chave e não como chaves diferentes, você precisará sobrescrever os métodos [equals()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/122978/como-sobrescrever-método-equals/122981) e [hashCode()](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11108/qual-a-import%C3%A2ncia-de-implementar-o-m%C3%A9todo-hashcode-em-java) da classe `Produto`.