# Setar item selecionado da ComboBox conforme clicado na jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jcombobox

Estou tentando preencher os campos de um formulário conforme o item clicado na jTable. Os campos de textos são preenchidos normalmente, mas a comboBox permanece com o valor default selecionado.

```
//método que preenche a comboBox
public void fillCBFornecedor(){
    fornCtrl = new FornecedorControle();
    cbFornecedor.removeAllItems();

    for(Object fornecedor: fornCtrl.listar()){
        cbFornecedor.addItem(fornecedor);
    }
}//aqui eu preencho a ComboBox com os itens trazidos da camada de controle(abaixo) que usa a camada DAO para fazer a busca no banco

//método que preenche a jTable
private void fillJTProdutos(){
    prodCtrl = new ProdutoControle();

    jtProdutos.removeAll();
    jtProdutos.setModel(prodCtrl);
}//aqui eu uso a camada de controle que implementa uma AbstractTableModel para preencher minha JTable

//preenche os campos conforme o item clicado
private void fillCampos(){
    txtProduto.setText((String) jtProdutos.getValueAt(jtProdutos.getSelectedRow(), 0));
    cbFornecedor.setSelectedItem(jtProdutos.getValueAt(jtProdutos.getSelectedRow(), 1));
    cbMarca.setSelectedItem(jtProdutos.getValueAt(jtProdutos.getSelectedRow(), 2));
    cbGenero.setSelectedItem(jtProdutos.getValueAt(jtProdutos.getSelectedRow(), 3));
    txtValor.setText(String.valueOf((Float) jtProdutos.getValueAt(jtProdutos.getSelectedRow(), 4)));
    txtMin.setText(String.valueOf((Integer) jtProdutos.getValueAt(jtProdutos.getSelectedRow(), 5)));
    txtMax.setText(String.valueOf((Integer) jtProdutos.getValueAt(jtProdutos.getSelectedRow(), 6)));
}
//atributos e métodos da camada de controle
public class ProdutoControle extends AbstractTableModel{

private final ProdutoDAO pDAO = new ProdutoDAO();
private Produto produto;
private Marca marca;
private Genero genero;
private Fornecedor fornecedor;

@Override
public String getColumnName(int coluna) {
    return colunas[coluna];
}

@Override
public int getRowCount() {
    return pDAO.buscar().size();
}

@Override
public int getColumnCount() {
    return colunas.length;
}

@Override
public Object getValueAt(int linha, int coluna) {
    switch(coluna){
        case 0:
            return pDAO.buscar().get(linha).getDescricao();
        case 1:
            return pDAO.buscar().get(linha).getMarca();
        case 2:
            return pDAO.buscar().get(linha).getGenero();
        case 3:
            return pDAO.buscar().get(linha).getFornecedor();
        case 4:
            return pDAO.buscar().get(linha).getValor_unitario();
        case 5:
            return pDAO.buscar().get(linha).getEstoque_min();
        case 6:
            return pDAO.buscar().get(linha).getEstoque_max();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}

//atributos e métodos da camada DAO
public class ProdutoDAO {

private Connection con = null;
private PreparedStatement stmt = null;
private ResultSet rs = null;
String sql = null;

private Produto produto;
private Fornecedor fornecedor;
private Marca marca;
private Genero genero;

public List<Produto> buscar(){
    con = ConexaoBanco.getConexao();
    List<Produto> produtos = new ArrayList<>();

    sql = "SELECT * FROM view_produtos";

    try{
        stmt = con.prepareStatement(sql);

        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        while(rs.next()){
            fornecedor = new Fornecedor();
            marca = new Marca();
            genero = new Genero();
            produto = new Produto(marca, genero, fornecedor);

            produto.setId(rs.getInt(1));
            produto.setDescricao(rs.getString(2));
            produto.getMarca().setDescricao(rs.getString(3));
            produto.getGenero().setDescricao(rs.getString(4));
            produto.getFornecedor().setRazao_social(rs.getString(5));
            produto.setValor_unitario(rs.getFloat(6));
            produto.setEstoque_min(rs.getInt(7));
            produto.setEstoque_max(rs.getInt(8));
            produto.setAtivo(rs.getInt(9));

            produtos.add(produto);
        }
    }
    catch(SQLException ex){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, ex, "Erro", 0);
    }
    finally{
        ConexaoBanco.fechar(con, stmt, rs);
    }
    return produtos;
}//na camada DAO faço um select na view de produtos e preencho um objeto com os dados trazidos.

//Inicialização da ComboBox

cbFornecedor = new javax.swing.JComboBox();
cbFornecedor.setToolTipText("");

//evento click do mouse na tabela
private void jtProdutosMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                        
    fillCampos();
}
```

Há alguma forma de definir o item selecionado na ComboBox conforme o item selecionado na JTable?

Comment: E se nenhuma linha estiver selecionada? Desativou multiseleção de linhas?

Comment: Não fiz nenhum tratamento do tipo. Do jeito que o código está agora os campos atualizam sempre que eu altero a seleção de linha (estou usando o método fillCampos() no evento MouseClicked da JTable). Quando não há nada selecionado na tabela (no carregamento da tela por exemplo) os campos simplesmente ficam vazio

Comment: Marca, Genero e Fornecer possuem algum campo de identificacao unico, como id? O motivo de não selecionar é que o objeto do combo não é o mesmo da sua tabela, pelo menos ao java. Você precisa "ensinar" o java como saber quando eles são iguais.

Comment: Sim, todos possuem um id. Como fazer essa verificação?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O método [`setSelectedItem()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html#setSelectedItem(java.lang.Object)) compara o objeto passado como parâmetro com os já existentes no combo utilizando o método `equals()`(código fonte deste método pode ser visto no [grepcode](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/javax/swing/JComboBox.java#JComboBox.setSelectedItem%28java.lang.Object%29)) que é herdado por todas as classes de `Object`.

Só que cada objeto criado não é igual a outro, mesmo que possuam os mesmos parâmetros e sejam do mesmo tipo, você pode fazer o teste imprimindo os objetos criados com os mesmos parâmetros dentro de um `System.out.println()`, o resultado será no formato `ClasseDoObjeto@hascode` e será diferente. Veja um teste no [ideone](https://ideone.com/9SsuMj).

Uma solução mais simples seria sobrescrever este método `equals` das classes `Marca`, `Genero` e `Fornecedor`, de modo a *"ensinar"* ao compilador em quais circunstâncias objetos destes tipos são iguais. Para ilustrar isso melhor, veja o método `equals` deste exemplo:

```
class MyClass {

    private int id;
    private String desc;

    public MyClass(int id, String desc) {
        this.id = id;
        this.desc = desc;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return this.id;
    }

    public String getDesc() {
        return this.desc;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            return  obj instanceof MyClass && this.id == ((MyClass)obj).getId();
    }
}
```

Só retornará `true` se os dois objetos forem do mesmo tipo e tiverem o campo `id` iguais.

No entanto, recomendo a leitura [desta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/122981/28595) em seus parágrafos finais, que fala sobre como seria a forma correta de sobrescrever este método e quais consequências de não seguir as recomendações.

---

Referência:

- [Compare two objects with .equals() and == operator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13387787/5524514)

Comment: Funcionou, obrigado! Além do seu código, percebi também que eu estava passando o número da coluna errado nos parâmetros, agora está funcionando perfeitamente.