# Qual o método mais eficiente para se remover um item do ArrayList?

Tags: java, desempenho, arraylist

Gostaria de saber qual dos métodos disponíveis pela classe `ArrayList` é mais eficiente para se apagar um item da lista.

Comment: O que você quer dizer com "eficiente"? As duas formas são eficientes, desde que se passe o indice ou objeto correto a ser excluido.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As duas formas fornecidas pela classe [`ArrayList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) são:

```
meuArrayList.remove(indice);
```

Onde `indice` é a posição do elemento na lista ou:

```
meuArrayList.remove(elemento);
```

Onde `elemento` é uma ocorrência exata de algum elemento que esteja na lista.

> **Observação**: a segunda forma só funcionará corretamente se sua lista for de algum tipo nativo do java(como String, Integer, etc...).
>   Se você criar objetos próprios, este método só funcionará corretamente
>   se sobrescrever o método `equals()`. [**Nesta
>   resposta**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/122981/28595) explica como
>   fazer isso de forma correta.

Segundo o código fonte dos métodos [`remove(index)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.remove%28int%29) e [`remove(Element)`](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/8u40-b25/java/util/ArrayList.java#ArrayList.remove%28java.lang.Object%29), pode-se perceber que a primeira opção não percorre toda a lista, removendo diretamente no índice do elemento, enquanto a segunda vai percorrer até encontrar a primeira ocorrência do elemento passado para remover.

Segue o código para testarmos a diferença:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class ArrayListRemocaoTest {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println("- Removendo o primeiro item/indice");       
        executarTeste("0");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("- Removendo um item/indice intermediario");
        executarTeste("5000");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("- Removendo o ultimo item/indice");
        executarTeste("9999");

    }

    private static void executarTeste(String valueIndex) {

        ArrayList<String> array1 = new ArrayList<>(10000);
        ArrayList<String> array2 = new ArrayList<>(10000);

        for(int i = 0; i < 10000; i++){
            array1.add(i+"");
            array2.add(i+"");
        }

        int indice = Integer.valueOf(valueIndex);

        long startTime = System.nanoTime();
        array1.remove(indice);
        long endTime = System.nanoTime();

        double duration1 = (endTime - startTime)/1000000d;

        System.out.println("Tempo de remoção do remove(index)(ms): " + String.format("%.3f", duration1));       

        startTime = System.nanoTime();
        array2.remove(valueIndex);
        endTime = System.nanoTime();

        double duration2 = (endTime - startTime)/1000000d;

        System.out.println("Tempo de remoção do remove(Element)(ms): " + String.format("%.3f", duration2));

        System.out.println("Diferença de tempo entre as duas formas: " + String.format("%.3f", (duration2-duration1)));
    }

}
```

No código acima há 3 testes que fiz utilizando a IDE eclipse, com duas listas com tamanho de 10.000 itens(o código pode ser testado no [**ideone**](https://ideone.com/tmZP9X)). Os testes são os seguintes:

- remover o primeiro elemento das listas com os dois métodos;
- remover um elemento intermediário(como o indice 5000) das listas com os dois métodos;
- remover o ultimo elemento das listas com os dois métodos;

E os resultados da execução foram:

```
- Removendo o primeiro item/indice
Tempo de remoção do remove(index)(ms): 0,022
Tempo de remoção do remove(Element)(ms): 0,036
Diferença de tempo entre as duas formas: 0,014

- Removendo um item/indice intermediario
Tempo de remoção do remove(index)(ms): 0,014
Tempo de remoção do remove(Element)(ms): 0,673
Diferença de tempo entre as duas formas: 0,659

- Removendo o ultimo item/indice
Tempo de remoção do remove(index)(ms): 0,035
Tempo de remoção do remove(Element)(ms): 1,339
Diferença de tempo entre as duas formas: 1,304
```

Perceba que nos três testes, remover pelo índice foi mais rápido, mas a diferença de tempo é quase irrisória. O resultado varia a cada execução, mas pode-se perceber uma pequena diferença entre ambos.

O que realmente impacta nos valores dos testes é que em ambas as formas de remoção, é criada uma cópia da lista, onde o índice que vai ser removido da lista é movido para ultima posição, e depois é aplicado `null` nesta posição, deixando o *Garbage Collector* fazer o restante.

Dependendo do uso de recursos do hardware nesse momento de cópia da lista, ainda mais se for uma lista de tamanho grande como a do teste acima, afetará o tempo do teste para mais ou para menos tempo. Se não quiser este comportamento, talvez o ideal é utilizar uma [LinkedList](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html).