# Verificar se ArrayList tem itens iguais

Tags: java, comparação

Tenho a classe `Pessoa`:

```
String Nome, Cidade;

public Pessoa(String Nome, String Cidade){
    this.Nome = Nome;
    this.Cidade = Cidade;
}


public String getNome() {
    return Nome;
}

public String getCidade() {
    return Cidade;
}
```

Tenho a classe que adiciona as `Pessoas` em uma `ArrayList`:

```
ArrayList<Pessoas> pessoas = new ArrayList<>();

public void cadastrarPessoas(){
    Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa(Nome, Cidade);
    pessoas.add(pessoa);
}
```

Como posso fazer retornar `true` se caso na lista de pessoas contém o elemento adicionado igual (exemplo abaixo): Pessoas pessoa = new Pessoa

```
Leandro|SP
Leandro|SP
```

Como eu queria:

```
Leandro|SP
Leandro|RC
```

Tentei esse jeito mas não acontece nada:

```
Pessoa pessoa2 = new Pessoa(Nome, Cidade);

    for (Pessoa pessoa : pessoas){
                if (pessoa.equals(pessoa2)){
                    iguais
                }else{
                    pessoas.add(pessoa2);
                    diferentes
                }
            }
```

Comment: Dê uma olhada, veja se te ajuda: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203984/how-do-i-remove-repeated-elements-from-arraylist)

Comment: Esqueci de mencionar que eu queria fazer um if se tiver repetido, como eu poderia fazer na resposta do tópico?

Comment: Você precisa fazer um comparator ou implementar o método equals, aqui no site já tem isso respondido.

Comment: Edite sua pergunta, adicione os detalhes, assim que for responder, tem ideia melhor do que precisa.

Comment: O método equals não funcionou, como posso fazer o comparador?

Comment: Já tentei pessoas.contains, equals e nada

Comment: Sugiro **[edit]** a pergunta, adicionando o código que vc já tentou (o método equals, etc), e qual foi o resultado e/ou mensagem de erro. Dizer simplesmente "já tentei e nada" é muito vago e não nos ajuda a te ajudar, pois não temos como saber exatamente onde vc está errando

Comment: Já editei e coloquei o código porém simplesmente não funciona, continua adicionando pessoas iguais

Comment: Você tem que sobrescrever o método `equals` na classe `Pessoas`, veja um exemplo [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/122978/112052). Outra coisa (não relacionada), é que a classe `Pessoas` representa apenas uma única pessoa, então eu mudaria o nome para `Pessoa` (no singular). Pode parecer um detalhe bobo, mas pra mim deixa o código um pouco menos confuso (não confunde a variável `pessoa` com a lista `pessoas`, etc).

Comment: Acho que vocês entenderam errado, eu queria retornar true se a lista Pessoas contém o: Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa vou editar e explicar melhor desculpa.

Comment: E como vc acha que o método `contains` de um `ArrayList` faz pra saber se um elemento pertence à lista? [**Usando o método `equals`**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#contains-java.lang.Object-). Como é um `ArrayList` de `Pessoas`, a classe `Pessoas` deve ter um método `equals` que diz qual é a regra para determinar que duas pessoas são iguais. Sem isso, o `contains` não tem como saber se 2 pessoas são iguais, e portanto não tem como saber se a pessoa pertence à lista.

Comment: No exemplo usei equals, porque preciso comparar a lista toda pra ver se é igual ao novo elemento que eu criei, porém não está acontecendo nada. Não quero criar dois elementos e comparar os dois

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Quando você cria a classe `Pessoa`:

```
public class Pessoa {
    private String nome;
    private String cidade;

    public Pessoa(String nome, String cidade) {
        this.nome = nome;
        this.cidade = cidade;
    }

    // ... getters e setters
}
```

Como fazer para saber se 2 instâncias desta classe são iguais? A primeira ideia é usar o operador `==`, já que ele funciona para números, então por que não funcionaria com objetos?

```
// primeira tentativa de comparar 2 pessoas
Pessoa p1 = new Pessoa("Fulano", "SP");
Pessoa p2 = new Pessoa("Fulano", "SP");
System.out.println(p1 == p2); // false
```

Só que esse código imprime `false`. Isso porque o operador `==` verifica se `p1` e `p2` são o mesmo objeto. Como cada um foi criado com `new`, eles são 2 objetos diferentes (embora com os mesmos valores).

Ah, mas espere, existe o método `equals`. Vamos tentar usá-lo?

```
// segunda tentativa de comparar 2 pessoas
Pessoa p1 = new Pessoa("Fulano", "SP");
Pessoa p2 = new Pessoa("Fulano", "SP");
System.out.println(p1.equals(p2)); // false
```

Esse código também imprime `false`. Isso acontece porque o método `equals` foi [herdado de `Object`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-), e internamente este método usa o operador `==`. Troquei 6 por meia-dúzia.

---

Para que eu considere 2 instâncias de `Pessoa` iguais **baseadas nos seus valores**, eu devo sobrescrever o método `equals`. Ou seja, a classe `Pessoa` deve ter sua própria versão de `equals`, com a regra que define o que faz 2 pessoas serem iguais.

No caso, 2 pessoas são iguais se os seus nomes e cidades são os mesmos, então o método ficaria assim:

```
public class Pessoa {
    ....

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        Pessoa other = (Pessoa) obj;
        // verifica se o nome e cidade são iguais
        return this.nome.equals(other.nome) && this.cidade.equals(other.cidade);
    }
}
```

Claro que esta implementação pode ser melhorada testando se os campos são `null`, se `obj` é mesmo uma instância de `Pessoa`, etc, mas vamos mantê-lo simples para fins didáticos.

Também é importante sobrescrever o método `hashCode`. [Neste link](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11114/112052) há uma boa resposta detalhando os motivos e como implementá-lo adequadamente. Aqui deixo a implementação sugerida pelo Eclipse, mas sugiro que leia o link indicado para entender melhor este método:

```
public class Pessoa {
    ....
    // equals, getters, setters, construtor, etc

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + ((cidade == null) ? 0 : cidade.hashCode());
        result = prime * result + ((nome == null) ? 0 : nome.hashCode());
        return result;
    }
}
```

Com isso, agora a classe `Pessoa` sabe verificar se outra `Pessoa` é igual a ela:

```
// terceira tentativa de comparar 2 pessoas
Pessoa p1 = new Pessoa("Fulano", "SP");
Pessoa p2 = new Pessoa("Fulano", "SP");
System.out.println(p1.equals(p2)); // true
```

Agora este código imprime `true`.

---

Com isso, se você tem uma lista de `Pessoa`, pode verificar facilmente se alguma `Pessoa` já pertence à lista:

```
// cria a lista e insere pessoas nela
List<Pessoa> listaPessoas = new ArrayList<>();
listaPessoas.add(new Pessoa("Fulano", "SP"));
listaPessoas.add(new Pessoa("Fulano", "RC"));

// verifica se uma pessoa qualquer pertence à lista
Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa("Fulano", "SP");
System.out.println(listaPessoas.contains(pessoa));
```

O método `contains` usa o método `equals` de `Pessoa` para saber se 2 pessoas são iguais, e com isso verifica se a `pessoa` já pertence à lista. Este código acima imprime `true` ("Fulano/SP" pertence à lista).

Claro que você também poderia fazer o `for` na lista e ir comparando cada pessoa com o método `equals`, mas para que fazer isso se `contains` faz exatamente a mesma coisa?

Além disso, você está fazendo um `for` na lista e adicionando um elemento nesta mesma lista dentro do `for`, o que vai gerar um `java.util.ConcurrentModificationException`. É melhor usar `contains` mesmo:

```
Pessoa pessoa = new Pessoa("Fulano", "SP");
// se a pessoa não pertence à lista, adiciona
if (! listaPessoas.contains(pessoa)) {
    listaPessoas.add(pessoa);
}
```

---

Mas se você quer uma coleção de várias pessoas sem ter repetidos, é melhor usar um `java.util.Set`, pois um *set* não permite elementos iguais:

```
// usar Set ao invés de List
Set<Pessoa> setPessoas = new HashSet<>();
// inserir pessoas
setPessoas.add(new Pessoa("Fulano", "SP"));
setPessoas.add(new Pessoa("Fulano", "RC"));
// tentar inserir Fulano/SP de novo
setPessoas.add(new Pessoa("Fulano", "SP"));

// imprime o tamanho do set
System.out.println(setPessoas.size());
```

Este código imprime `2`, pois o `Set` só terá 2 elementos. A segunda tentativa de inserir "Fulano/SP" não funciona, pois ele já pertence ao `Set`.

Se eu usasse `List`, teria que verificar se o elemento já pertence à lista antes de adicioná-lo (o que também funciona, mas usar `Set` elimina este passo).

---

Se **mesmo assim** você precisa de um `List`, pode criá-la a partir do `Set`:

```
// cria um List com os elementos do Set
List<Pessoa> listaPessoas = new ArrayList<>(setPessoas);
```

---

Outra maneira de implementar o `hashCode` é usando um `java.util.Objects` (no plural, não confundir com `java.lang.Object` (no singular)):

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    // calcula o hashCode usando nome e cidade
    return Objects.hash(cidade, nome);
}
```

Comment: Entendi, estou usando contains no Set<> porém ele só me retorna false, o List<> também retornava só false quando eu usava, e é muito estranho porque os dados são iguais no List<> mas acho que no Set<> ele não adiciona iguais

Comment: @Slinidy Exato, no `List`, elementos iguais podem ser inseridos várias vezes, no `Set` não. Mas o `Set` só vai saber se 2 pessoas são iguais se vc implementar `equals` e `hashCode`

Comment: Não sei oque está acontecendo mais meu Set<> está inserindo valor repetido, mesmo com contains e não podendo inserir, vou editar e mostrar todos os valores pegos do for

Comment: @Slinidy Se o `Set` está aceitando repetidos, é pq os métodos `equals` e `hashCode` não estão corretamente implementados

Comment: Funcionou obrigado, poderia me explicar porque você colocou prime = 31 result = 1 ?

Comment: @Slinidy Usei o gerador automático do Eclipse, que coloca uma implementação padrão dele. Na verdade vc pode usar qq número, desde que obedeça algumas regras, como "se 2 pessoas forem iguais (`equals` retorna `true`), seus hashCodes também devem ser iguais, etc". Sugiro que [leia o link que passei](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/11114/112052), que explica mais detalhes sobre o hashCode

Comment: @Slinidy Aqui tem uma discussão sobre isso: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11795104/is-the-hashcode-function-generated-by-eclipse-any-good

Comment: @Slinidy Agora terei que sair, mas qualquer dúvida podemos continuar amanhã. Se a sua dúvida não for mais relacionada a equals e hashcode, sugiro que faça outra pergunta, para não misturar os assuntos. Boa noite!

Comment: Coisa boba minha, funcionou perfeitamente, obrigado. Boa noite!