# Problema ao exibir dados Many to Many

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Estou com  problemas na hora de exibir o resultado da consulta. Não estou conseguindo exibir os resultados de maneira correta.

tenho as seguintes tabelas e registros:

```
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `livraria`;
USE livraria;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `categoria` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` VARCHAR(45) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `livro` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `categoria_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `nome` VARCHAR(60) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `categoria_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`categoria_id`) REFERENCES 
`categoria` (`id`)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `autor` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `nome` VARCHAR(60) NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
ENGINE = InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `livro_autor` (
  `livro_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `autor_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`livro_id`, `autor_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `livro_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`livro_id`) REFERENCES `livro` (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `autor_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`autor_id`) REFERENCES `autor` (`id`)
)ENGINE = InnoDB;



INSERT INTO categoria (`nome`) VALUES ('Ação'), ('Aventura'), ('Terror');
INSERT INTO autor (`nome`) VALUES ('Fulano'), ('Sicrano'), ('Beltrano');
INSERT INTO livro (`categoria_id`, `nome`) VALUES (1, 'Explosão Total'), (1, 'Piloto Mariano'), (3, 'Terror no hotel da rua 3');

INSERT INTO livro_autor (`livro_id`, `autor_id`) VALUES (1, 1), (1, 2), (2, 3);

# TESTE

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM livro l 
INNER JOIN categoria c ON l.categoria_id = c.id
INNER JOIN livro_autor la ON l.id = la.livro_id
INNER JOIN autor a WHERE a.id = la.autor_id;

+----+--------------+----------------+----+----------+----------+----------+----+----------+
| id | categoria_id | nome           | id | nome     | livro_id | autor_id | id | nome     | 
+----+--------------+----------------+----+----------+----------+----------+----+----------+
| 1  | 1            | Explosão Total | 1  | Ação     | 1        | 1        | 1  | Fulano   |
+----+--------------+----------------+----+----------+----------+----------+----+----------+
| 1  | 1            | Explosão Total | 1  | Ação     | 1        | 2        | 2  | Sicrano  |
+----+--------------+----------------+----+----------+----------+----------+----+----------+
| 2  | 1            | Piloto Mariano | 1  | Ação     | 2        | 3        | 3  | Beltrano  |
+----+--------------+----------------+----+----------+----------+----------+----+----------+
```

No java eu tenho as minhas classes:
Autor, Categoria, Livro, com a implementação básica de um **javabean**, tenho também a classe que representa o relacionamento **muitos para muitos LivroAutor**

```
public class LivroAutor {

    private Livro livro;
    private Autor autor;

    public Livro getLivro() {
        return livro;
    }
    public void setLivro(Livro livro) {
        this.livro = livro;
    }
    public Autor getAutor() {
        return autor;
    }
    public void setAutor(Autor autor) {
        this.autor = autor;
    }
}
```

Também tenho a classe LivroDao com o método `listAll()`:

```
public List<Livro> listAll() {
    PreparedStatement stmt = null;
    ResultSet rs = null;
    String sql = "SELECT DISTINCT * FROM livro l " + 
            "INNER JOIN categoria c ON l.categoria_id = c.id " + 
            "INNER JOIN livro_autor la ON l.id = la.livro_id " + 
            "INNER JOIN autor a WHERE a.id = la.autor_id";
    try {
        stmt = this.conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        rs = stmt.executeQuery();

        List<Livro> livros = new ArrayList<>();
        List<LivroAutor> listaAutores =  new ArrayList<>();

        while (rs.next()) {
            Livro livro = new Livro(rs.getInt("l.id"), rs.getString("l.nome"));
            Categoria categoria = new Categoria(rs.getInt("c.id"), rs.getString("c.nome"));
            Autor autor = new Autor(rs.getInt("a.id"), rs.getString("a.nome"));

            LivroAutor livroAautor = new LivroAutor();
            livroAautor.setAutor(autor);

            listaAutores.add(livroAautor);


            livro.setCategoria(categoria);
            livro.setAutores(listaAutores);

            livros.add(livro);

        }
        rs.close();
        stmt.close();
        this.conn.close();

        return livros;


    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

o JSP está assim:

```
    <table class="table table-hover table-striped table-sm">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>id</th>
                <th>Livro</th>
                <th>Categoria</th>  
                <th>Autores</th>    
                <th>Ações</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
                <jsp:useBean id="livro" class="br.com.livraria.dao.LivroDao" />
                <c:forEach var="liv" items="${livro.listAll()}">
                <tr>
                    <td>${liv.id}</td>
                    <td>${liv.nome}</td>
                    <td>${liv.categoria.nome}</td>
                    <td>
                        <c:forEach var="aut" items="${liv.autores}">
                            ${aut.autor.nome}, 
                        </c:forEach>
                    </td>

                    <td>
                        <a href="#">Editar</a>
                        <a href="#">Excluir</a>    
                    </td>
                </tr>
                </c:forEach>
        </tbody>    
    </table>
```

e o resultado é o seguinte

https://postimg.cc/dDNKMbSw

Conforme o resultado apresentado na imagem acima, não foi o esperado...

Se alguém tiver alguma dica de como resolver a dúvida apresentada na imagem, onde há uma repetição de registros e como exibir apenas os autores que escreveram o livro. Muito Obrigado.

**Obs*:** Poderia usar o JPA/Hibernate com a anotação @ManyToMany e tudo mais, mas é justamente por não saber fazer na unha que estou estudando o jdbc e surgiu essa dúvida

Valeu galera!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No momento não tenho como fazer teste no mysql então fiz no
>   postgresql

Na sua classe `Livro` altere o campo `autores` para receber uma lista do tipo Autor apenas com gets e sets atualizados:

`public class Livro {
   ...
   List<Autor> autores = new ArrayList<>();
   ...
  // gets and sets
}`

Sua query tem um pequeno erro na cláusula `WHERE` não é preciso desta cláusula, pois você está fazendo um select sem filtro (eu imagino usando o WHERE para buscar algum livro específico ou categoria específica), o correto seria:

`SELECT DISTINCT * FROM livro l 
INNER JOIN categoria c ON l.categoria_id = c.id
INNER JOIN livro_autor la ON l.id = la.livro_id
INNER JOIN autor a on a.id = la.autor_id;`

Com isso você vai obter os mesmo resultados:

```
+----+--------------+----------------+----+----------+----------+----------+----+----------+
| id | categoria_id | nome           | id | nome     | livro_id | autor_id | id | nome     | 
+----+--------------+----------------+----+----------+----------+----------+----+----------+
| 1  | 1            | Explosão Total | 1  | Ação     | 1        | 1        | 1  | Fulano   |
+----+--------------+----------------+----+----------+----------+----------+----+----------+
| 1  | 1            | Explosão Total | 1  | Ação     | 1        | 2        | 2  | Sicrano  |
+----+--------------+----------------+----+----------+----------+----------+----+----------+
| 2  | 1            | Piloto Mariano | 1  | Ação     | 2        | 3        | 3  | Beltrano  |
+----+--------------+----------------+----+----------+----------+----------+----+----------+
```

Agora podemos agrupar por autor e adicioná-los em seus respectivos livros.
No seu método **listAll()** :

```
    ...
    List<Livro> livros = new ArrayList<>();
    //1 -List<LivroAutor> listaAutores =  new ArrayList<>();

    while (rs.next()) {
        Livro livro = new Livro(rs.getInt("l.id"), rs.getString("l.nome"));
        Categoria categoria = new Categoria(rs.getInt("c.id"), rs.getString("c.nome"));
        Autor autor = new Autor(rs.getInt("a.id"), rs.getString("a.nome"));

        //1 -LivroAutor livroAautor = new LivroAutor();
        //1 -livroAautor.setAutor(autor);

        //1 -listaAutores.add(livroAautor);


        livro.setCategoria(categoria);
        //1 -livro.setAutores(listaAutores);

        int index = livros.indexOf(livro);
        if (index == -1) {
            livros.add(livro);
        }else {
            Livro livroExistente = livros.get(index);
            livroExistente.getAutores().add(autor);
        }

    }
   ...
```

No seu JSP altere o foreach:

```
<td>
   <c:forEach var="aut" items="${liv.autores}">
        ${aut.nome}, 
   </c:forEach>
</td>
```

Explicação:

- A primeira coisa a fazer é alterar o campo autores para receber uma lista de Autor. Quando tenho um relacionamento N - N, ele é na verdade um relacionamento 1 - N onde **UM** **autor** pode ter vários **livros** e **UM** **livro** pode ter vários **autores**. Se minha 3° tabela faz apenas referências a *ids* eu não criaria uma classe para representa-la. O mesmo pode ser feito na classe `Autor` criar um campo com a lista de Livros que pertence a ele.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

- Com isso retire ou comente o código que faz referência a classe `LivroAutor`.
  O método `indexOf()` busca a primeira ocorrência do elemento na lista e retorna a posição ou retorna `-1` caso este elemento não está presente na lista. É bem simples se o livro já exista apenas adiciono um novo autor a este livro.

> É importante que sua classe livro esteja com os métodos equals e
>   hashcode implementados. [Resposta aqui no stack sobre.](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/11108/qual-a-import%C3%A2ncia-de-implementar-o-m%C3%A9todo-hashcode-em-java)
>    [Algaworks-Equals and hashCode](https://blog.algaworks.com/entendendo-o-equals-e-hashcode/)