# Java 8 - Percorrer lista, alterar caso encontrado, se não, adicionar

Tags: java, java-8, stream

Em uma aplicação de carrinho de compras, tenho dentro da classe `CarrinhoCompras` o seguinte atributo:

```
List<Item> itens = new ArrayList<>();
```

E um método para adicionar item, que recebe um produto, seu valor unitário e a quantidade. O que a função faz é procurar na `ArrayList` de itens se o produto passado como parâmetro já está no carrinho. Caso o item esteja, altera seu valor e caso não esteja adiciona um novo item.

Estou querendo resolver puramente com o recurso das *streams*, mas acho que estou fazendo processamento demais para isso. O método tem o seguinte código:

```
public void adicionarItem(Produto produto, BigDecimal valorUnitario, int quantidade) {

    itens.stream().filter(item -> item.getProduto().equals(produto)).findAny()
    .map(item -> {
        item.setQuantidade(item.getQuantidade() + quantidade);
        item.setValorUnitario(valorUnitario);
        return item;
    }).orElseGet(() -> {

        itens.add(new Item(produto, valorUnitario, quantidade));
        return null;

    });
}
```

Alguém sabe um jeito de fazer essa verificação sem ter que passar por tanto processamento?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se está preocupado com processamento, *talvez* não devesse usar *streams*, já que elas [têm o seu custo](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22670380) e por isso [são mais lentas que um *loop* tradicional](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/361945/112052).

Outro ponto é que talvez você esteja complicando o código à toa. Nem sempre você precisa de *streams*. O seu código poderia ficar assim:

```
public void adicionarItem(Produto produto, BigDecimal valorUnitario, int quantidade) {
    for (Item item : itens) {
        if (item.getProduto().equals(produto)) {
            item.setQuantidade(item.getQuantidade() + quantidade);
            item.setValorUnitario(valorUnitario);
            return; // achou o item, pode sair do método
        }
    }
    // se chegou aqui é porque não encontrou um item com o mesmo produto
    itens.add(new Item(produto, valorUnitario, quantidade));
}
```

---

Mas se quer mesmo usar *stream*, talvez usar `map` não seja a melhor escolha, pois este método serve para transformar um valor em outro (por exemplo, `map(item -> item.getProduto())` faz com que o valor original (item) seja "transformado" no seu respectivo produto).

Usar `map` para fazer algo com o item e em seguida retorná-lo - apesar de funcionar - é um "uso torto" deste método. O mesmo vale para `orElseGet`, que você usa como se fosse um `else` (no qual o `if` equivalente é o `map`), e retorna `null`, somente porque algo tem que ser retornado (sendo que `orElseGet` serve para retornar um valor *default* caso o `findAny` não encontrasse nada).

Um jeito mais simples é obter o resultado de `findAny`, que é um [`Optional`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html) - ou seja, ele representa um valor que pode ou não existir. Em seguida, basta verificar se o valor existe ou não, e tomar as respectivas ações em cada caso:

```
public void adicionarItem(Produto produto, BigDecimal valorUnitario, int quantidade) {
    Optional<Item> opt = itens.stream().filter(item -> item.getProduto().equals(produto)).findAny();
    if (opt.isPresent()) {
        opt.get().setQuantidade(opt.get().getQuantidade() + quantidade);
        opt.get().setValorUnitario(valorUnitario);
    } else {
        itens.add(new Item(produto, valorUnitario, quantidade));
    }
}
```

---

No **Java 9**, você pode usar o método [`ifPresentOrElse`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresentOrElse-java.util.function.Consumer-java.lang.Runnable-), que recebe as ações a serem feitas caso o valor do `Optional` exista ou não. Então ficaria assim:

```
public void adicionarItem(Produto produto, BigDecimal valorUnitario, int quantidade) {
    itens.stream().filter(item -> item.getProduto().equals(produto)).findAny()
      .ifPresentOrElse( // este método é somente para Java >= 9
        item -> { // se já existe, atualiza os valores
            item.setQuantidade(item.getQuantidade() + quantidade);
            item.setValorUnitario(valorUnitario);
        },
        () -> { // se não existe, adiciona na lista
            itens.add(new Item(produto, valorUnitario, quantidade));
        }
      );
}
```

Se estiver usando Java 8, você pode implementar [algo parecido com isso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29395324). Mas sinceramente, acho um exagero ter que criar uma estrutura adicional somente para poder fazer um único encadeamento. Nem sempre isso é possível, ou estritamente necessário, e muitas vezes nem será a melhor solução.

---

Os algoritmos acima percorrem a lista até encontrar um `Item` que tenha o `Produto` indicado. No pior caso, você terá que percorrer toda a lista para saber se o produto está nela. Se quiser melhorar esta busca, pode trocar o `List` para um `java.util.Map`.

Como você usou `equals` para comparar produtos, estou assumindo que os métodos `equals` e `hashCode` estão devida e corretamente implementados (veja [esta pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11108/112052) e [este artigo](https://www.baeldung.com/java-hashcode) para mais detalhes sobre estes métodos).

Basicamente, podemos usar um `Map` que faz o mapeamento de produtos para seus respectivos itens:

```
Map<Produto, Item> map = new HashMap<>();
```

E o método para adicionar produtos ficaria assim:

```
public void adicionarItem(Produto produto, BigDecimal valorUnitario, int quantidade) {
    if (map.containsKey(produto)) {
        Item item = map.get(produto);
        item.setQuantidade(item.getQuantidade() + quantidade);
        item.setValorUnitario(valorUnitario);
    } else {
        map.put(produto, new Item(produto, valorUnitario, quantidade));
    }
}

// imprimir os itens
for (Item item : map.values()) {
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

Sinto te desapontar, mas para este caso a melhor solução também não usa *streams*. Com o `Map` é bem fácil verificar se já existe um item correspondente ao produto sendo adicionado. E escolhi um `HashMap` como implementação, pois segundo a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html), faz a busca em tempo constante (melhor que a busca linear feita no `ArrayList`).

Claro que, se quiser, você também pode usar *stream*:

```
Optional<Item> opt = map
    .entrySet()
    .stream()
    // encontrar chave igual ao produto
    .filter(entry -> entry.getKey().equals(produto))
    // obter o respectivo valor
    .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
    .findFirst();
```

Mas aqui caímos no mesmo problema da solução anterior. O resultado é um `Optional`, e para encadear tudo você teria que usar `ifPresentOrElse` (para Java >= 9), ou as soluções já propostas para o Java 8 (a solução [deste link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29395324) ou o código que sugeri com `isPresent()`).

Sinceramente, não acho que *streams* seja a melhor solução para este caso. E se for para forçar tudo em um único encadeamento, pior ainda. O ideal é escolher a solução mais adequada para o problema, em vez de tentar "encaixar" uma solução que "eu quero/preciso usar", mesmo que não seja a melhor opção.

Comment: Fiz usando streams pois nesta situação (foi um teste técnico) me foi pedido que fossem usados recursos do Java 8, e tentei retornar todo o processamento em um único encadeamento de comandos mas o avaliador comentou que o código "fazia uma busca linear" e que haviam melhores opções. Não tem como realizar este processo em uma única pipeline de chamadas à stream sem fazer um "uso torto" das funcionalidades então?

Comment: @CaiqueRibeiro Em Java 9 tem [isso](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42669868). Em Java8 tem [essa](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29395324), mas sinceramente acho um exagero criar toda essa estrutura extra só pra isso. Sobre a busca linear, uma opção para evitar é usar Map ou Set, no lugar de List. Assim que puder atualizo a resposta com essas opções :-)