# Ao imprimir um array os elementos não são mostrados

Tags: java, array

Estou tentando resolver um problema onde tenho que ler as linhas de um arquivo .txt e separar os numeros desta linha e salvar em um vetor.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        FileReader arq = new FileReader("Teste.txt");
        BufferedReader lerArq = new BufferedReader(arq);
        
        int[][] num = new int[20][20];
        String lerLinha = "";
        String[] linha = new String[30];
        
        lerLinha = lerArq.readLine();
        System.out.println(lerLinha);
        linha = lerLinha.split(" ");
        System.out.print(linha);
}
```

Executando esse código ele retorna:

```
61 57 18 -73 74 -19 15 -70 -16 -8 -80 -6 2 -85 8 22 73 -44 34 1
[Ljava.lang.String;@15db9742
```

Queria saber como resolver esse problema com a variável `linha` que esta retornando esse `java.lang.String;@15db9742`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quando encontra um problema assim busque na documentação como aquele método funciona. Aliás, não use um método sem ler e entender toda documentação dele e o que for relacionado.

[Documentação do `split()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String)).

E lá diz que o retorno desse método é um *array* de *strings*. Portanto há vários elementos no objeto. Qual dos elementos você quer imprimir? Não está especificando, está falando para imprimir o objeto todo e ele não sabe como fazer isso, ele só sabe pegar a referência do objeto, que é o que foi impresso.

Então ou você diz qual é o elemento do *array* que quer imprimir (`linha.get(0)`) ou faz um laço para pegar todo os elementos e imprimir cada um deles, algo assim:

```
for (String item : linha) System.out.print(item);
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Array/PrintItems3.java).

Essa variável `item` será uma `String`, porque todos elementos do *array* são desse tipo, e é um tipo que ele sabe imprimir perfeitamente.

Answer (score 0):

`linha` é um array de `String`'s, e quando você imprime um array com `System.out.println(array)`, internamente é chamado o método `toString()` do mesmo. Só que arrays herdam este método de [`Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html), cujo código é:

```
// método toString de java.lang.Object
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Ou seja, ele retorna o nome da classe e o [hashcode](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/11108/112052) da mesma. No caso de arrays, a [documentação](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#getName--) explica que a quantidade de `[` representa a dimensão do array (no caso, é unidimensional, mas se fosse um array de arrays, por exemplo, seria `[[`), e `L` é o prefixo que indica que os elementos do array são de uma classe (e logo depois vem o nome da classe). Por isso que a saída começa com `[Ljava.lang.String`.

Ou seja, imprimir um array diretamente não vai mostrar os elementos do mesmo.

Se quer imprimir os elementos, pode fazer um *loop* como já sugeriu a [outra resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/469594/112052), ou pode usar [`Arrays.toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#toString-java.lang.Object:A-):

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(linha)); // [61, 57, 18, -73, 74, -19, 15, -70, -16, -8, -80, -6, 2, -85, 8, 22, 73, -44, 34, 1]
```

A diferença é que `Arrays.toString` retorna um formato fixo (elementos separados por vírgula, delimitados por colchetes). Para fins de *debug* pode ser o suficiente, mas se quiser um formato diferente, não tem jeito, precisa fazer um *loop* e imprimir no formato desejado.

Outro detalhe é que `Arrays.toString` internamente chama o método `toString()` de cada elemento. Ou seja, se os elementos forem de uma classe que não implementa `toString()`, a saída será um monte de `nomedaclasse@hashcode`. Como no seu caso específico o array contém `String`'s, este problema não ocorre.

E no caso específico de um array de `String`'s, você também pode usar [`String.join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#join-java.lang.CharSequence-java.lang.CharSequence...-) (disponível a partir do Java 8):

```
System.out.println(String.join(" | ", linha)); // 61 | 57 | 18 | -73 | 74 | -19 | 15 | -70 | -16 | -8 | -80 | -6 | 2 | -85 | 8 | 22 | 73 | -44 | 34 | 1
```

O `join` junta todos os valores do array em uma única `String`, e você pode escolher o separador (usei `" | "` como exemplo, mas poderia ser qualquer outro).