# Como usar função para somar 3 matrizes

Tags: java, array, funções, matriz

Estou com problemas para criar uma função. Estou com meu programa pronto, porém estou fazendo um exercício onde a função é obrigatória e não estou conseguindo.

```
Java

   public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random aleatorio = new Random();

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Digite a quantidade de linhas das matrizes: ");
        int linhas = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Digite a quantidade de colunas das matrizes: ");
        int colunas = input.nextInt();

 /      
 int[][] matriz1 = new int[linhas][colunas];
        for (int i = 0; i < matriz1.length; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < matriz1[i].length; j++) {
                matriz1[i][j] = aleatorio.nextInt(9);
                System.out.printf("%d ", matriz1[i][j]);
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
 \

//Para fazer a matriz 2 e 3 copiei a parte de cima (A parte entre / \ )
   

//Aqui na soma é onde preciso de uma função

        int[][] resultado = new int[linhas][colunas];

        if (linhas == colunas){
            for (int i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++) {
                for (int j = 0; j < resultado[i].length; j++) {
                    resultado[i][j] = matriz1[i][j] + matriz2[i][j] + matriz3[i][j];
                    System.out.printf("%d ", resultado[i][j]);
                }
                System.out.println();
            }
        }else{
            System.out.printf("A soma nao eh possivel");
        }
        input.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

É só criar a função que recebe as 3 matrizes (e os tamanhos) e retorna o resultado:

```
static int[][] soma(int linhas, int colunas, int[][] matriz1, int[][] matriz2, int[][] matriz3) {
    int[][] resultado = new int[linhas][colunas];

    for (int i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < resultado[i].length; j++) {
            resultado[i][j] = matriz1[i][j] + matriz2[i][j] + matriz3[i][j];
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}
```

E no `main`, basta chamar a função passando os dados:

```
// passa a matrizes a serem somadas, e a quantidade de linhas e colunas
int[][] resultado = soma(linhas, colunas, matriz1, matriz2, matriz3);

// depois, faz o que quiser com o resultado
for (int[] linha : resultado) {
    for (int valor : linha) {
        System.out.printf("%5d", valor);
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

---

Eu também poderia pegar o tamanho de uma das matrizes - neste caso, estou assumindo que os tamanhos são compatíveis:

```
static int[][] soma(int[][] matriz1, int[][] matriz2, int[][] matriz3) {
    int linhas = matriz1.length;
    int colunas = matriz1[0].length;
    int[][] resultado = new int[linhas][colunas];

    for (int i = 0; i < resultado.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < resultado[i].length; j++) {
            resultado[i][j] = matriz1[i][j] + matriz2[i][j] + matriz3[i][j];
        }
    }
    return resultado;
}

// e no main
int[][] resultado = soma(matriz1, matriz2, matriz3);
```

Retirei o `if (linhas == colunas)` porque não faz sentido. A única condição que impede a soma é se as matrizes tiverem dimensões diferentes (mas se a quantidade de linhas e colunas for diferente, não impede, desde que todas tenham o mesmo tamanho: por exemplo, todas poderiam ser 4 x 2, ou 10 x 20, etc, que a soma continuaria sendo possível).

Comment: Eu tentei fazer iso e coloquei no main isso:                                                                                         int[][] resultado = soma(linhas, colunas, matriz1, matriz2, matriz3);         
System.out.println("Soma das matrizes = " + resultado);                                                                           Mas daí o resultado da soma não funciona, e diz:                                                                Soma das matrizes = [[I@511baa65

Comment: @boltJu Se imprimir um array diretamente, o resultado vai ser esse mesmo (tem uma explicação [aqui](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/469637/112052)) - se quiser imprimir os valores, tem que fazer o `for` que fiz ali (`for (int[] linha : resultado) etc..`)